# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have seen that other people have had the same problem, but their fixes did not work for me.

When I download tidyverse:

```
install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.7.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1057786 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
** package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c base64.c -o base64.o
sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: base64.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'jsonlite'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/jsonlite'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/jsonlite'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\laura\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO6mvhP\downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘dplyr’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
rlang       0.4.5  0.4.9              TRUE
tidyselect  1.0.0  1.1.0              TRUE
vctrs       0.2.4  0.3.5              TRUE
dplyr       0.8.5  1.0.2              TRUE
broom       0.5.6  0.7.2             FALSE
dbplyr      1.4.3  2.0.0             FALSE
modelr      0.1.6  0.1.8             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 439648 bytes (429 KB)
downloaded 429 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\laura\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpO6mvhP\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘rlang’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘dplyr’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_0.4.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 865299 bytes (845 KB)
downloaded 845 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 90842 bytes (88 KB)
downloaded 88 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1055792 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_1.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 935654 bytes (913 KB)
downloaded 913 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 616998 bytes (602 KB)
downloaded 602 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 534910 bytes (522 KB)
downloaded 522 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121333 bytes (118 KB)
downloaded 118 KB

* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o
sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: capture.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'vctrs' ...
** package 'vctrs' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c altrep-rle.c -o altrep-rle.o
sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: altrep-rle.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'vctrs'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/vctrs'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/vctrs'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'tidyselect' ...
** package 'tidyselect' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyselect'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'dplyr' ...
** package 'dplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c filter.cpp -o filter.o
sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: filter.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'dplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dplyr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
** package 'dbplyr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : object 'relocate' is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'broom' is not available for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/laura/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Then when trying to upload:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘broom’

I'm not sure why this is happening, I downloaded rtools which it asked for... But not sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: Can you format this so it's readable?  Which part of those 30 paragraphs is your question and which part is error messages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with loading tidyverse: package or namspace laod failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633120/error-with-loading-tidyverse-package-or-namspace-laod-failed)