# Error with loading tidyverse: package or namspace load failed

Tags: r, tidyverse

I just downloaded R (version 4.0.3) and RStudio (1.3.1093). The packages seem to be installed okay but when I try to load tidyverse, the following error messege appears:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
undefined exports: check_dots_empty, check_dots_unnamed, check_dots_used, safe_median
In addition: Warning message:
S3 method ‘safe_median.numeric’ was declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

I recently downloaded R and RStudio (the same versions) on another computer and it was okay. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling R and RStudio, removing the packages and installing them again. Furthermore, I've gone through the numerous stackoverflow posts on similar problems but nothing has worked.

I'd be incredibly grateful for a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are all from the `ellipsis` package. It is possible that all of the `tidyverse` packages installed properly, but that there is something wrong with the install of the `ellipsis` package. Try installing the `ellipsis` package, and then the `tidyverse`.

Comment: Yes but that may miss the fact that function triggers only a _Warning_ whereas OP is struck by the preceding _Error_.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was thinking similarly, but the error about `check_dots_empty` is still likely related to `ellipsis`. So perhaps the incorrect symptom but a likely cure?

Comment: Yes, that could be.