# My tidyverse is not loading, when I type in library(tidyverse) an error shows up, why?

Tags: r, tidyverse

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in
> namespaceExport(ns, exports):  undefined exports: check_dots_empty,
> check_dots_unnamed, check_dots_used, safe_median In addition: Warning
> messages: 1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3  2:
> S3 method ‘safe_median.numeric’ was declared in NAMESPACE but not
> found

Comment: You may have consider updating R to the most recent release and updating all your packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same problem with this question. You need to check **ellipsis** package.

[question] : [Error with loading tidyverse: package or namspace laod failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633120/error-with-loading-tidyverse-package-or-namspace-laod-failed)

Comment: If this is a duplicate of a previous post, flag it as such so it can be closed, rather than answer with just a link